# Oddly shaped volume

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

What is the volume of the solid where the base is the triangular region with vertices at (0,0), (0,2) and (3,0). The cross sections perpendicular to the y-axis are semicircles.

My set up is: $$V = \int_0^2 \frac{\pi}{2} (\frac{-3y}{4} + \frac{3}{2})^2 dy$$

Yielding $$ = \frac{3\pi}{4} $$

Is my set up correct?

Comment: Your setup is correct but your calculation is not.  The value of the integral you wrote should be $3\pi/4$.

Comment: Yep you're right, evidently I cannot reduce fractions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a plot of what is given:

[image]

The radius of that arbitrary section is $r=\frac{6-3y}{4}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3y}{4}$ so the volume of that section is $V_{dy}=\pi r^2/2$ and so $$V=\int_0^2\frac{\pi}2r^2dy$$

Comment: lol what program is that

Comment: @qwr: It is one of my instance hand made. :D